# offline ovi map in desktop application

Tags: dictionary, ovi

I want to embed Ovi Maps in a desktop application in offline(but interactive) mode. GIven that these maps and their related map APIs are mainly targeted for mobile platforms, is this possible ? If so, can anyone point to any existing documentation on how to do this? Any pointers to existing examples would be a plus. 
I considered using google Maps which can be integrated with desktop applications, but they cannot be used in offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, even if you can use Ovi Maps in your desktop application (using Nokia Qt C++ SQK with Location API, see http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility/location-overview.html) you cannot use Ovi Maps in offline mode and there is currently no way to embed it (offline maps use is only possible on Nokia mobile devices that embed maps by default).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The latest branding of Ovi Maps has changed to Nokia Maps. The new  - [Nokia Maps Framework for Mobile HTML5](http://api.maps.nokia.com/en/mobile/index.html) claims to have offline support. The API relies on the user using a browser which supports local storage, so provided your user base is using Google Chrome or Safari it would work on a desktop as well as various mobile platforms.

An example app can be found with the documentation

The offline claim can be found [here](http://lanyrd.com/2012/over-the-air/jun-01/)